# @Timed annotation to generate Distribution Summary

Tags: micrometer, spring-micrometer

Micrometer @Timed Annotation generates Timer, which when exported to datadog, only provides sum, min, max, median, 95 percentile functionality.
To get p50,p75,p90 etc in datadog, the metric should be of type distribution. How can i change the meter generated from @Timed to distribution summary.

Answer (score 1):

Old question but just found the answer searching for the same thing:

```
@Timed(value = "your.name.here",histogram = true,percentiles = {0.5,0.75,0.90} )
```

Answer (score 0):

A `Timer` is already a distribution in Micrometer. It is a special one though because it records duration and it also gives you a convenient way to measure elapsed time.

You can call `.publishPercentiles(0.5, 0.75, 0.90)` on the builder to get those percentiles published, also you can call `.publishPercentileHistogram()` to publish histograms, please see the docs: https://micrometer.io/docs/concepts#_histograms_and_percentiles